# Problems with the transformation of the Region $T$ using coordinate changes.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> 

Calculate the inertial moments
$I_x$, $I_y$, $I_z$ respect of the coordenate planes of one homemogenius solid $T$ given by
$(\frac{x^2 } {a^2 }+ \frac{y^2 } {b^2 } +\frac{z^2 } {c^2 })^2 =\frac{x^2 } {a^2 } +\frac{y^2 } {b^2 }-\frac{z^2 } {c^2 } $.where $a, b, c>0$.>
My book defines
$I_x=\int \int \int_W (x^2 +y^2 ) \delta dxdydz$ where $\delta$ is the density in each point of the solid $W$

I can't visualize $T$, the first thing that I think can be useful is a coordinate change given by $x=au$, $y=bv$, $z=cw$.
Following this I get that $T$ becomes
$(u^2 +v^2 +w^2)^2 =u^2 +v^2 - w^2 $
Now applying a coordenate change to spherical coordinates, we have the follow expression for $T$
Like a $\rho^2=-Cos(2 \phi) $ now is possible assume that $T$ in this new region is
$0< \rho \leq \sqrt{-cos(2\phi)} $,  $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ and $0 \leq \phi \leq \pi$ and rempleaze
$x^2 +y^2 $ for $(bv) ^2 +(cw) ^2 $ and too
$b^2 \rho^2 sen^2 \phi sen^2 \theta+c^2 \rho^2 cos^2 \phi$. And  my assumption of the triple integral is

$$\int_{0} ^{2\pi} \int_{0} ^{\pi} \int_{0 } ^{ \sqrt{-cos(2\phi)} }( b^2 \rho^2 sen^2 \phi sen^2 \theta+c^2 \rho^2 cos^2 \phi) \rho^2 sin^2 \phi d\rho d\phi d\theta$$

I'm correct or probably do a mistake?
When I get the new region $T$ in the spherical coordinates in the $(u, v, w)$ space

Any help will be appreciated and useful.

Answer (score 0):

Recordemos que el momento de inercia paraun cuerpo sólido $W$ respecto de un plano coordenado está dado por $$ I_{XY}=\int \int \int_{W}z^2 \delta dxdydz $$
$$ I_{XZ}=\int \int \int_{W}y^2 \delta dxdydz $$

$$I_{YZ}=\int \int \int_{W}x^2 \delta dxdydz$$\
dónde $\delta$ es la densidad del sólido $W$ en cualquier punto.\
Para cálcular $I_{YZ}$ de manera más simple, es necesario transformar la región $T$ en una región más simple, considere el cambio de variable dado por $x=au$,$y=bv$, $z=cw$, de manera que el Jacobiano de la transofromación está dado por $|J|=abc$. Nuestro sólido $T$, en el $(u,v,w)$ espacio se ve como el sólido $T^{\prime}$ dado por la expresión $$(u^2+v^2+w^2)^2=u^2+v^2-w^2$$ Dentro de nuestro $(u,v,w)$ espacio consideremos una transformación a coordendas espéricas dada por $u=\rho sin \phi cos \theta$, $v=\rho sin \phi sin \theta$, $w=\rho cos \phi$, la deformación que sufrio $T^{\prime}$ está dada por $|J^{\prime}|=\rho^2 sin\phi$.\
Con este cambio de variable, tenemos que el sólido  $T^{\prime}$ ahora esta dado por $T^{\prime \prime}$ que tiene por ecuación
$$\rho^4=\rho^2(sin^2 \phi-Cos^2 \phi)$$
$$\rho^2=-cos 2\phi(\rho \neq 0)(\rho^2 \geq 0)$$
$$\rho= \pm \sqrt{-cos 2\phi}$$
Como $\rho^2 \geq 0$ entonces $-1 \leq cos 2\phi \leq 0$, de esto es fácil ver que $  \frac{\pi}{4}\leq \phi \leq \frac{3 \pi}{4}$.\

Remplazando en nuestra expresión para $I_{XY}$, tenemos que

$$I_{XY}=\int \int \int_{T^{\prime \prime}}z^2 \delta dxdydz$$

$$I_{XY}= \delta \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{-cos 2\phi}}(c^2)(abc) \rho^2 cos^2 \phi  \rho^2 sin \phi)  d\rho d\phi d\theta $$
$$ I_{XY}= \delta abc^{3} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}}sin \phi cos^2 \phi  d\phi d\theta  \int_{0}^{\sqrt{-cos 2\phi}} \rho^4 d\rho $$
$$ I_{XY}= \delta abc^{3} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}}sin \phi cos^2 \phi \frac{1}{5} cos^2 2\phi \sqrt{-cos 2\phi}  d\phi d\theta $$
$$ I_{XY}= \delta\frac{1}{5} abc^{3} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}}sin \phi cos^2 \phi cos^2 2\phi \sqrt{-cos 2\phi}  d\phi d\theta $$
Haceindo $u=cos \phi$ , $ du=-sin \phi d\phi$ nos queda
$$ \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}}sin \phi cos^2 \phi cos^2 2\phi \sqrt{-cos 2\phi}  d\phi= -\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}} \sqrt{1-2u^2}u^2(2u^2-1)^2 du $$ realizando las operciones algebráicas obtenemos $$ \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}} 4u^6 \sqrt{1-2u^2}-4u^4 \sqrt{1-2u^2}+u^2 \sqrt{1-2u^2}$$
Tomando ahora $u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}Sin \alpha $, $du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}cos \alpha d\alpha$,$\sqrt{1-2u^2}=cos \alpha$ y remplazando en la integral y separando en sumas, e sustituyendo en el primer sumando conseguimos
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}}4u^6 \sqrt{1-2u^2}= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}} sin^6 \alpha cos^2 \alpha d\alpha$$ Usando que $cos^2 \alpha=1-sin^2 \alpha$
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}} sin^6 \alpha-sin^2 \alpha$$
Estas integrales se hacen con la fórmula de reducción, y usando la propiedad de línealidad de la integral, cada uno de todos los sumandos se hace con un procedimiento análogo, por lo que juntndo todos los resultados de cada integral conseguimos ver que
$$ \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}}sin \phi cos^2 \phi cos^2 2\phi \sqrt{-cos 2\phi}  d\phi=\frac{5 \pi}{256 \sqrt{2}}$$
Ahora sólo integramos
$$ \frac{5 \pi}{256 \sqrt{2}} \delta\frac{1}{5} abc^{3} \int_{0}^{2\pi} d\theta $$
$$ \frac{5 \pi}{256 \sqrt{2}} \delta\frac{1}{5} abc^{3} 2\pi $$ por tanto
$$I_{XY}=\int \int \int_{T^{\prime \prime}}z^2 \delta dxdydz=\frac{2 \pi^2 abc^3 \delta}{256\sqrt{2}}$$.\
Ahora calculemos $I_{XZ}$.\
$$ I_{XZ}=\int \int \int_{T^{\prime \prime }}y^2 \delta dxdydz $$
$$I_{XZ}= \delta \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{-cos 2\phi}}(b^2)(abc) \rho^2 sin^2 \phi  \rho^2 sin^2 sin \phi )  d\rho d\phi d\theta $$

$$ I_{XZ}= \delta ab^{3}c \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}}sin^2 \theta sin^3 \phi d\phi d\theta  \int_{0}^{\sqrt{-cos 2\phi}} \rho^4 d\rho $$

$$ I_{XZ}= \delta ab^{3}c \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}}sin^3 \phi sin^2 \theta \frac{1}{5} cos^2 2\phi \sqrt{-cos 2\phi}  d\phi d\theta $$

$$ I_{XZ}= \delta\frac{1}{5} ab^{3}c \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}} sin^3 \phi sin^2 \theta cos^2 2\phi \sqrt{-cos 2\phi}  d\phi d\theta $$
Calculamos $$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}} sin^3 \phi cos^2 2\phi \sqrt{-cos 2\phi} d\phi=\frac{75 \pi}{256 \sqrt{2}}$$ por tanto
$$ I_{XZ}= \delta\frac{1}{5} ab^{3}c \frac{75 \pi}{256 \sqrt{2}} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} sin^2 \theta d\theta $$
Como $$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} sin^2 \theta d\theta= \pi $$
Por tanto
$$\pi \delta\frac{1}{5} ab^{3}c \frac{75 \pi}{256 \sqrt{2}}=\frac{ 15 \delta ab^3c \pi^2}{256 \sqrt{2}}$$
En consecuencia
$$ I_{XZ}=\int \int \int_{T^{\prime \prime }}y^2 \delta dxdydz = \frac{ 15 \delta ab^3c \pi^2}{256 \sqrt{2}}$$
Finalmenete calculamos $I_{YZ}$\
$$ I_{YZ}=\int \int \int_{T}x^2 \delta dxdydz $$

$$I_{YZ}= \delta \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{-cos 2\phi}}(a^2)(abc) \rho^2 sin^2 \phi cos^2 \theta \rho^2 sin \phi )  d\rho d\phi d\theta $$

$$ I_{YZ}= \delta a^{3}bc \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}}sin^3 \phi cos^2 \theta \frac{1}{5} cos^2 2\phi \sqrt{-cos 2\phi}  d\phi d\theta $$

$$ I_{YZ}= \delta\frac{1}{5} a^3bc \int_{0}^{2 \pi} \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}} sin^3 \phi cos^2 \theta cos^2 2\phi \sqrt{-cos 2\phi}  d\phi d\theta $$

Calculamos $$\int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{3 \pi}{4}} sin^3 \phi cos^2 2\phi \sqrt{-cos 2\phi} d\phi=\frac{75 \pi}{256 \sqrt{2}}$$ por tanto
$$ I_{YZ}= \delta\frac{1}{5} a^{3}bc \frac{75 \pi}{256 \sqrt{2}} \int_{0}^{2 \pi} sin^2 \theta d\theta $$
Como $$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} cos^2 \theta d\theta= \pi $$

Por tanto
$$\pi \delta\frac{1}{5} a^{3}bc \frac{75 \pi}{256 \sqrt{2}}=\frac{ 15 \delta a^{3}bc \pi^2}{256 \sqrt{2}}$$

$$ I_{YZ}=\int \int \int_{T^{\prime \prime }}x^2 \delta dxdydz = \frac{ 15 \delta a^{3}bc \pi^2}{256 \sqrt{2}}$$